# Unwanted line break between elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have a text input and a button using `bootstrap` but for some reason there's unwanted line break created between them. I'm new to `bootstrap` so I'm not sure what's going on.

```
<div class="row" style="border:0px solid black">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="border:0px solid green"></div> 

  <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8" style="border:2px solid green">    

  <p:autoComplete id="acSimple" value="#{home.searchKeywords}" completeMethod="#{home.completeText}" size="65" /> <!-- size="65" -->

  <p:commandLink action="#{home.goToSearchResults}" onclick=" $('.prgrs').show();">
  <h:graphicImage name="images/searchbutton.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:-0px;"  />
  </p:commandLink>
  </div>        

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="border:2px solid green"></div>
</div>
```

This is the end result:

[image]

and what I need is for the `button` to be just to the right of the `text input`.

EDIT: Once I use `display: inline-block;` as per one of the answers it works for larger screens, but not for smaller ones. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Please check are you using different rows in your code for textbox and image button.

Also use display: inline-block; 
use for the button use :float: right; and left for the text box.

Comment: What you are showing is not html code. How can you want others to make an effort and read your code and try to help *if you're not even willing to make an effort in showing a proper code example*? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for both: `display: inline-block;` for the button use `float: right;` for the text input use `float: left;`

Comment: Actually this works for larger screens but not for smaller ones. I edited the question with a screenshot.

Comment: Well, it seems like you're using bootstrap, bootstrap already has responsiveness to it, so I don't see why this should happen, can you post a jsfiddle? also, it seems like you're using 2 divs of `col-xs-2` in order to center your `col-xs-8` div, you could simply use offset for that.

Comment: display: inline-block; on the image, and fixing the bootstrap issues did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must know, not only the page but also every division will be divided into 12 columns.
And in your code, you have filled up all these columns by the following:

```
     <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="border:0px solid green"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8" style="border:2px solid green"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="border:2px solid green"></div>
```

This has a complete coverage of the whole page.
 So., the master division could be given a class 'col-md-12'
The following code must help:

```
<div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="border:0px solid black">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="border:0px solid green"></div> 
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8" style="border:2px solid green"></div>        
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="border:2px solid green"></div>
</div>
```